# How to avoid a Column resize in React-grid-system?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, col

Hello i have a simple 2 column page , the left one is a column md={1} and the right one md={11}(**import { Container, Row, Col} from 'react-grid-system';**) the thing is that inside the left one i have a div with a sidebar made by me. I simply want that the left column does not resize but stays still and when the page get small it just go up the right one. Now this already happen but before the page get small like a smartphone or an ipad the left column starts to resize so the right column goes over the div inside the left column and is horrible even if is just for a while. I just want that the left column always keep hes position until the page becomes so small that he has to go up like already he does for default by the react-grid-system.

```
   `<Row>
     <Col md={1} >
        <Sidebar/>
      </Col>
        
      <Col md={11}>
          <Routes/>
      </Col>
    </Row>`
```

The side bar has a div inside and is not important to know how i handle that because i dont want that div to resize i want that the sidebar stays hes position always until it gets small the page and it goes up , thing that as i said already works. The only **problem** is that the column where the div is md={1} resize when the page resize i just want that it resize when arrive to the small page size. Is there any method for set this thing?

---

fullpagesize_sidebar{md1} | fullpagesize_main md{11}

---

mdpagesize_sidebar{md1} | mdpagesize_main md{resize}

---

|smallpagesize_sidebar{md12}| 
 |smallpagesize_main{md12}|

---

For now they do the same except for the middle size where it happens this :
 mdpagesize_sidebar{resize} | mdpagesize_main md{resize}